# Extracting data from scanner string passed into method

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am required to pass a scanner as a parameter to a method and have the method print things based on what was passed with the scanner.

So, if the scanner passed contains "6 fox 3 bees 2 25 8 ducks"
The method would print out

```
foxfoxfoxfoxfoxfox 

beesbeesbees  
2525  
ducksducksducksducksducksducksducksducks
```

I have no problem writing the method.  I'm just confused as to how I would use a scanner to do that.

Comment: are you reading form the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read from the `Scanner` using methods like `next()` and `nextInt()`. You can read the full `Scanner` javadoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Comment: Scanner is the type like int and other types in Java, so how do you pass other types into functions do the same to do Scanner type :)

Comment: Yeah yeah.  I forgot about whitespace delimiters. I am shameful.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a `Scanner` is used for reading stuff in from either a file or standard input (`System.in`).  Passing *it* around wouldn't do you a whole lot of good unless you want to encapsulate functionality and responsibilities.

If we think about this from a problem-solving stance, what are we really trying to get?

- We have a string that contains first a number and a string, and the second string could contain numerals.
- All of these symbols are separated by space.
- Everything is contained on one line; we don't have to worry about moving to the next line.

It's entirely up to you how you want to approach this, but a couple of suggestions are as follows:

- Since you know the precise order of tokens, you can make multiple calls to `Scanner.next()` and `Scanner.nextInt()`.

  ```
  while(scanner.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println(readFromScanner(scanner));
  }
  scanner.close(); // DO NOT DO THIS if you are using System.in!

  public static String readFromScanner(Scanner scanner) {
      StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
      int times = scanner.nextInt();
      String phrase = scanner.next();
      for(int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
          result.append(phrase);
      }
      return result.toString();
  }
  ```
- You could also read the entire line in at once using `nextLine()`, and parse it using `String.split()`, which gives you numerals at every even index (0, 2, 4, etc), and strings at every odd index (1, 3, 5, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Try this. There are two ways of reading input.

1) InputStreamReader wrapped in a BufferedReader

2) Scanner classes in JDK1.5

Refer to this article. This will solve your problem.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-input-from-console-java/

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a Parameter by :

Input Accept here

```
  System.out.println("Input here: " );
  String input = scan.next();

  // This how you gonna pass the parameter
  inputedByScanner(input);
```

Your Method Accept it and print the inputed value.

```
public void print inputedByScanner(String input){
   System.out.println(input);
}
```

Comment: So I'd use another method inside that, then?

Comment: @ChristopherBaldwin is it really mandatory for you to pass Scanner type to your function? are you trying to read a file or read from console?

Comment: @ChristopherBaldwin you just call the method name then pass the parameter in it. then it automatically print what you had inputted

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Homework {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter something:");
        doStupidHomework(new Scanner(System.in));
    }

    private static void doStupidHomework(Scanner scanner) {
        int i = 0, x = 0;
        for (String next = scanner.next(); next != null; next = scanner.next(), i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                x = Integer.parseInt(next);
                continue;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
                System.out.print(next);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Enter something:
6 fox 3 bees 2 25 8 ducks
foxfoxfoxfoxfoxfox
beesbeesbees
2525
ducksducksducksducksducksducksducksducks
```